# How to open an application from widget in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

When we click the widget at that time I need to open an activity screen (or application). How to do this?

Answer (score 20):

You need to set an onClickpendingIntent on your widget

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
// Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
```

Check this out

[Processing more than one button click at Android Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471875/processing-more-than-one-button-click-at-android-widget)

Comment: Side question, can you extract activities for a specific app ? (maybe I don't know what class is ExampleActivity.class )

Comment: who upvoted this nonesense? where's the answer? the guy asked "how to open an application from the widget button" not "how to set an action on a widget button"

Comment: @AlirezaJamali To open the application from the widget button, just use your main activity as `ExampleActivity.class` in the first line.

Comment: The second line should be `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);` (with `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` instead of the last `0`), otherwise you get a "Missing PendingIntent mutability flag" warning.

Answer (score 11):

Include this code in yout WidgetProvider class's onUpdate() method.

```
for(int j = 0; j < appWidgetIds.length; j++) 
{
    int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[j];

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("your Application package",
            "fully qualified name of main activity of the app"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, intent, 0);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            layout id);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(view Id on which onclick to be handled, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    "There was a problem loading the application: ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: "your Application package","fully qualified name of main activity of the app" means `intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), MainActivity.class.getName());`

Answer (score 4):

very simple(In xamarin c# android mono):

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (ViewClick.Equals(intent.Action))
            {
                var pm = context.PackageManager;
                try
                {
                    var packageName = "com.companyname.YOURPACKAGENAME";
                    var launchIntent = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
                    context.StartActivity(launchIntent);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Something went wrong :)
                }
            }
            base.OnReceive(context, intent);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Android developer pages for App Widgets has information and a full example doing exactly this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score 1):

**Using Kotlin**

You need to add `PendingIntent` on Click of your widget Views

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetRoot, 
               PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java), 0))
```

Where *widgetRoot* is the id of my widget's parent `ViewGroup`

**In On Update**

Pending intent is usually added in **onUpdate** callback

```
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray) {

        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        val widgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds( ComponentName(context, ClockWidget::class.java))
        for (appWidgetId in widgetIds) {

                // Construct the RemoteViews object
                val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.clock_widget)

               //Open App on Widget Click
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.weatherRoot,  
   PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java), 0))

                //Update Widget 
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appWidgetText, Date().toString())
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
            }
        }
    }
```