# How to open other application from widget in android?

Tags: android, widget

When we click the widget at that time i need to open an external aplication (for example netflix app).How to do this?

[image]

In all cases i find solutions like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589741/how-to-open-a-application-from-widget-in-android) but, is not what I'm looking.

Thanks!!