# android - Widget button click count

Tags: android, android-widget

Here's the thing:

I have a widget and on it are many buttons.  Now, I want to keep track if buttons are clicked from widget.  In a normal layout:

```
public void onClick(...){
     // other codes
     Log.d("", "clicked");
}
```

How about in widget? Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471875/processing-more-than-one-button-click-at-android-widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the onclickpendingintent like this

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagebutton, R.drawable.buttonw);
Intent i = new Intent(context, top.class);
i.putExtra("widget", "1");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imagebutton, pendingIntent);
```

it's an example to set onclick to an imageview that will launch the application when the imageview clicked

if you have any question feel free to ask in the comment

Comment: i have next,imgeview,prv button when i am click next then next image show in imagview.how to possible