# Android Homescreen Widget becomes Unresponsive

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an Android home screen widget I am working on and everything works great, except after about 5 to 6 days the four buttons revert to their default state and become unresponsive. I do not understand why the buttons are becoming unresponsive. If I remove and add the widget again it works again. If I wait for about 24-48 hours, it will begin to work again for a period of time.

I have tried to remove the `android:updatePeriodMillis` so that the widget does not update on its own (it is self-contained and only really needs updated upon user interaction). This has not worked either.

This is how I am setting up my `PendingIntents` within`onUpdate` (modeled after the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471875/processing-more-than-one-button-click-at-android-widget)):

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
intent1.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
intent1.setAction(FIRST_INTENT);
intent1.setData(Uri.parse(first_band_intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.first_button, pendingIntent1);
```

I then update the widget's view items within the `onReceive` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int widgetID = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
    String preferences = PREFS + Integer.toString(widgetID);
    SharedPreferences values = context.getSharedPreferences(preferences, 0);
    int firstBandValue = values.getInt("first_band_value", 1);
    int secondBandValue = values.getInt("second_band_value", 0);
    int multiplierValue = values.getInt("multiplier_value", 2);
    int toleranceValue = values.getInt("tolerance_value", 1);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(FIRST_BAND)) {
        // nextBandColor() will set the proper band based on the next value and return an integer that is BandValue + 1
        firstBandValue = getNextBandColor(context, BandType.FIRST, firstBandValue);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = values.edit();
        editor.putInt("first_band_value", firstBandValue);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(SECOND_BAND)) {
        // nextBandColor() will return an integer that is BandValue + 1
        secondBandValue = getNextBandColor(context, BandType.SECOND, secondBandValue);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = values.edit();
        editor.putInt("second_band_value", secondBandValue);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(MULTIPLIER)) {
        // nextBandColor() will return an integer that is BandValue + 1
        multiplierValue = getNextBandColor(context, BandType.MULTIPLIER, multiplierValue);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = values.edit();
        editor.putInt("multiplier_value", multiplierValue);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(TOLERANCE)) {
        // nextBandColor() will return an integer that is BandValue + 1
        toleranceValue = getNextBandColor(context, BandType.TOLERANCE, toleranceValue);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = values.edit();
        editor.putInt("tolerance_value", toleranceValue);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    //Update the view items based on the new integer values; calls updateAppWidget()
    updateBands(context, widgetID, firstBandValue, secondBandValue, multiplierValue, toleranceValue);

    // Concatenate the integer value of the first band value with the integer value of the second band color
    String value = Integer.toString(firstBandValue) + Integer.toString(secondBandValue);

    // Turn the concatenation of the two integers into a double value
    baseValue = Double.parseDouble(value);

    multiplyBaseValue(multiplierValue);

    String units = getUnitsAndAdjustBaseValue();
    String tolerance = getTolerance(toleranceValue);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    resistance = df.format(baseValue) + units + tolerance;

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.resistance_value, resistance);


    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, remoteViews);
}
```

This widget is designed to be stand-alone, without any Activity or Service.

**UPDATE 1:** If I add a `return` statement to the else of my `onReceive` after the `super.onReceive()`, then it reverts to the original layout, but does not become unresponsive.

**UPDATE 2:** I read [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html) that the `onReceive()` method must complete processing within 5 seconds. Could the issue be that my `onReceive()` is not completing within the allotted time and thus causing the widget to freeze?

This issue is also device independent. It has happened on a Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7 2012, and Galaxy S4.

What could be causing the issue of this unresponsiveness?

Comment: You'll need to post your onReceive() code as well as any Activity and Service code you have in the app.  Your desktop widget is really just a BroadcastReceiver, so you have to follow the same rules you follow for BRs.  The BR callback as well as the Activity and Service callbacks all happen on the main UI thread, so if you're doing anything which could block it will cause problems.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I have updated with my onReceive code. Thank you for the suggestion. I thought the issue was with the PendingIntents.

Comment: No problem, let me know if that helped.  If it doesn't just add some more of your app code above and we can all take a closer look.  Good luck!

Comment: Did you find the solution finally?

Comment: @CarlosHernándezGil Not yet, but I have also taken quite a long sabbatical from this project...

Answer (score 0):

Test your `onReceive()` code first to see if the error lies in there or elsewhere - it is always best to test assumptions when looking for "random" or "weird" bugs.

So to test it, simplify it absolutely, to make it 100% trivial. Remove all the interesting code, and just make it change the text to something simple. Something that could no possibly have a bug in it.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int widgetID = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.resistance_value, "1.2 ohms");

    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, remoteViews);
}
```

If this still breaks, then you know the bug is not within your `onReceive()` code. So you can then look elsewhere.

---

If this fixes the issue, then you know that part of your `onReceive()` has broken the widget.

Add the code back bit by bit, add lots of logging (`Log.d()`).

You may want to look at your `SharedPreferences` access, since this is file access. Also have a look at this post, and consider using `SharedPreferences.Editor.apply()`:

- [What's the difference between commit() and apply() in Shared Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference)

---

Typically with this approach, you will be able to find the bug, or at least narrow it down to something really specific, which will make it easier to get help here.