# Android widget becomes unresponsive after random amounts of time pass

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent, remoteview

My assumption is that I just do not fully understand widgets yet.  Hopefully one of you guru's can see where my logic/thinking is flawed.

Ultimately what happens with my widget is that it eventually becomes unresponsive at very random intervals (usually > 5 hours).

My investigation so far has led me to believe that it's potentially a result of the OS running low on memory and my widget being recreated?

If that's the case, I would have thought that the OnUpdate() method would handle this but potentially I'm wrong here.

I have read pretty much every thread on here regarding widget unresponsiveness.  The only one that showed promise for me was this one:

[Android Homescreen Widget becomes Unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714532/android-homescreen-widget-becomes-unresponsive)

but I'm not using a service and not sure I need to.

The goal of the widget is to first check if the user has created a profile.  This is done by checking for the existence of a local db along with a user record.  If neither of these exist, the widget should display a "Get Started" image (which it does successfully).

Once the user taps on this image, they are launched into a profile creation wizard.  Once the profile is created, the widget is updated from the app to display an image along with some caloric intake information.

There are three clickable items on the widget.  The image and the two textviews.  Each respectively launching a different activity in my app.

Here is the widget class:

```
public class bbi_widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    private static String week6Path = "";

    public static RemoteViews getWidgetRemoteViews(Context context) {
        Intent calorieCrushIntent = new Intent(context, calorie_crush.class);
        Intent dashBoardIntent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);

        PendingIntent calorieCrushPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, calorieCrushIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent dashboardPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, dashBoardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews appWidgetViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.initial_widget_layout);

        appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, calorieCrushPendingIntent);
        appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.calTextView, calorieCrushPendingIntent);
        appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_after_picture, dashboardPendingIntent);

        return appWidgetViews;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {

        BBIDatabase db = new BBIDatabase(context);

        db.openToRead();

        boolean doesTableExist = db.doesTableExist(BBIDatabase.BBI_USER_TABLE);

        db.close();

        boolean doesUserExist = false;

        if (doesTableExist){
            db.openToRead();
            doesUserExist = db.doesUserExist();
            db.close();
        }

        if (!doesTableExist || !doesUserExist){
            Intent getStartedIntent = new Intent(context, GettingStartedWizardActivity.class);

            PendingIntent getStartedPendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0, getStartedIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            for (int index = 0; index < appWidgetIds.length; index++) {
                int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[index];
                RemoteViews appWidgetViews = getWidgetRemoteViews(context);

                appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_after_picture, getStartedPendingIntent);

                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetViews);
            }
        } else {

            db.openToRead();

            String curPath = db.GetSixWeekPath();

            Bitmap sixWeekBmp = null;
            if (week6Path != curPath && curPath != null && week6Path != null) {
                week6Path = db.GetSixWeekPath();
                sixWeekBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(week6Path);
            }

            db.close();

            db.openToRead();


            int totalCalsToday = db.GetTodaysCalorieIntakeForWidget();
            int bmrWithAct = db.GetBMRPlusActivity();
            int additionalCalsCrushed = db.GetTodaysCaloriesBurnedForWidget();

            int surp = totalCalsToday - (bmrWithAct + additionalCalsCrushed);
            if (surp < 0)
                surp = 0;

            int def = totalCalsToday - (bmrWithAct + additionalCalsCrushed);
            if (def > 0)
                def = 0;

            db.close();

            for (int index = 0; index < appWidgetIds.length; index++) {
                int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[index];
                RemoteViews appWidgetViews = getWidgetRemoteViews(context);

                appWidgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.calTextView, View.VISIBLE);
                appWidgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, View.VISIBLE);

                appWidgetViews.setTextViewText(R.id.calTextView, "Calorie intake: " + String.valueOf(totalCalsToday));

                if (surp > 0) {
                    appWidgetViews.setTextViewText(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, "SURPLUS   " + String.valueOf(surp));
                    appWidgetViews.setTextColor(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.surplus_ball_color));
                } else {
                    appWidgetViews.setTextViewText(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, "DEFICIT   " + String.valueOf(def));
                    appWidgetViews.setTextColor(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.calorie_crush_ball));
                }

                appWidgetViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_after_picture, sixWeekBmp);

                Intent calorieCrushIntent = new Intent(context, calorie_crush.class);
                Intent dashBoardIntent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);

                PendingIntent calorieCrushPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context, 0, calorieCrushIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                PendingIntent dashboardPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context, 0, dashBoardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, calorieCrushPendingIntent);
                appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.calTextView, calorieCrushPendingIntent);
                appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_after_picture, dashboardPendingIntent);

                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetViews);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From my app, I do update these values in the widget using remoteViews.

Here is the helper class in my app:

```
public class WidgetHelper {

    public static void UpdateCalorieIntake(int newValue, Context context) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.initial_widget_layout);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, bbi_widget.class);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.calTextView, "Calories in  " + String.valueOf(newValue));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    public static void UpdateWidgetSurplus(int newValue, Context context) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.initial_widget_layout);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, bbi_widget.class);

        if (newValue > 0) {
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, "Caloric Surplus  " + String.valueOf(newValue));
            remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.surplus_ball_color));
        } else {
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, "Caloric Deficit  " + String.valueOf(newValue));
            remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.calorie_crush_ball));
        }
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    private static String week6Path = "";

    public static void UpdateAll(Context context) {
        BBIDatabase db = new BBIDatabase(context);

        db.openToRead();

        String curPath = db.GetSixWeekPath();

        Bitmap sixWeekBmp = null;
        if (week6Path != curPath && curPath != null && week6Path != null) {
            week6Path = db.GetSixWeekPath();
            sixWeekBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(week6Path);
        }

        db.close();

        db.openToRead();

        int totalCalsToday = db.GetTodaysCalorieIntakeForWidget();
        int bmrWithAct = db.GetBMRPlusActivity();
        int additionalCalsCrushed = db.GetTodaysCaloriesBurnedForWidget();

        int surp = totalCalsToday - (bmrWithAct + additionalCalsCrushed);
        if (surp < 0)
            surp = 0;

        int def = totalCalsToday - (bmrWithAct + additionalCalsCrushed);
        if (def > 0)
            def = 0;

        db.close();

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews appWidgetViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.initial_widget_layout);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, bbi_widget.class);

        appWidgetViews.setTextViewText(R.id.calTextView, "Calorie intake: " + String.valueOf(totalCalsToday));

        if (surp > 0) {
            appWidgetViews.setTextViewText(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, "Caloric surplus  " + String.valueOf(surp));
            appWidgetViews.setTextColor(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.surplus_ball_color));
        } else {
            appWidgetViews.setTextViewText(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, "Caloric deficit  " + String.valueOf(def));
            appWidgetViews.setTextColor(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.calorie_crush_ball));
        }

        appWidgetViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_after_picture, sixWeekBmp);

        Intent calorieCrushIntent = new Intent(context, calorie_crush.class);
        Intent dashBoardIntent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);

        PendingIntent calorieCrushPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, calorieCrushIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent dashboardPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, dashBoardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.surp_def_widgettextView, calorieCrushPendingIntent);
        appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.calTextView, calorieCrushPendingIntent);
        appWidgetViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_after_picture, dashboardPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, appWidgetViews);
    }
}
```

Provider infor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="294dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/bbi_icon"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/initial_widget_layout"
    >

</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: Did you find the culprit of your unresponsiveness? I'm having the same issue.