# best practice to register click listeners to widgets

Tags: android

To register a click listener for a button in android you can

1) instantiate the button and create an in-line event listener

2) implement the click listener interface on the activity and provide the method in the activity

3) Define the click method in the xml layout of the activity and define the method in the activity

i was wondering is there a best approach, i like to implement the interface. Is it  bad to name the method in the xml as then you would need to also include it in any other version of the layout ie landscape

Comment: Check out any available tutorial or reference, e.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html; if you are looking for a button on a widget (as your title suggests) check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082998/how-to-implement-a-button-on-an-android-widget

Comment: On one of a video tutorials I watched(I can't remember from where), author advised to use your 2nd method. His explanation was it was slow to create an innerclass everytime an event was fired. In implementing interface method event is listened at the activity level itself. Atleast that's what he said. I never confirmed it. My projects were small ones and it never mattered enough. Also you are asking for widgets, which I have no Idea.

Answer (score 0):

second approach is rather simple and make the code a lot cleaner but most of the time you may need to have mixed approach of 1st and 2nd.